# .NET Specification

Tags: .net, .net-core, любой-язык, code-style

Я давным давно познакомился с таким типом как `CLSCompliantAttribute`. Идея проста: ограничить интерфейс высокоуровневых языков и дать относительно низкоуровневым языкам возможность взаимодействовать с ним. Но когда я перешёл с .NET Framework на .NET Core, оказалось, что расширения от Microsoft (по типу `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`) не являются CLS-совместимыми.

Тогда возникает логичный вопрос: раз `CLSCompliantAttribute` не используют даже его создатели, то зачем он нужен в 2020 г.?

Есть ли языки, которые не могут без него жить?

Comment: JS или какой-нибудь IronPython не имеют signed-типов и поэтому хотят CLS-compliant. Но если вы пишете конфигурацию, вам придётся не давать ее вот так прямо модулям на JS (что кажется более-менее логичным).

Comment: @VladD, может `unsigned`?

Comment: @Grundy: Точно, не имеют unsigned-типов

Comment: У каждого атрибута своя область применения. Вы ж не перестанете пользоваться sealed оттого, что у Майкрософт на все классы в BCL так маркированы?

Comment: @VladD, _https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/2689_ там у них что-то странное с добавлением этого атрибута :)

Comment: @Grundy: Ага, решили не заморачиваться. Но это легко решается написанием обёртки.

Comment: @VladD, Каким образом? На обертку ж нельзя поставить этот атрибут, потому что она использует сборку без этого атрибута

Comment: @Grundy: вроде ж это не проблема? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4975659/276994

Comment: @VladD, тогда я не совсем понял, что не нравилось в тикете :) раз в принципе все ок :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Есть ли языки, которые не могут без него жить?

Языкам, по существу, до лампочки этот аттрибут. Языкам требуется API, который они переваривают, а атрибут CLSCompliant они могут использовать, чтобы вывести предупреждение во время компиляции при попытке использовать неподдерживаемый API. А могут и не использовать. Реальность находится ближе ко второму варианту. Чтобы проиллюстировать это, создадим экспериментальную заготовку для взаимодействия "низкоуровневого" С# и высокоуровневого JScript.NET:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.JScript;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static object JsExecute(
            string script, 
            string[] refs,
            string func, 
            params object[] args)
        {
            var jsc = new JScriptCodeProvider();
            var parameters = new CompilerParameters( refs, "test.dll", true);
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;

            CompilerResults results = jsc.CompileAssemblyFromFile(parameters, new string[] { script });

            if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Errors: ");

                foreach (var err in results.Errors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(err.ToString());
                }

                return null;
            }            

            var ass = results.CompiledAssembly;
            var c = ass.GetType("C");
            var f = c.GetMethod(func);
            return f.Invoke(null, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Чтобы это заработало, нужно добавить ссылку на Microsoft.JScript (и проект должен быть .NET Framework - в .NET Core нет нужных типов для интеграции с JS). Собственно, код берет скрипт из файла, компилирует и запускает отражением. Обращаю внимание, что `results.Errors` помимо ошибок включает также предупреждения, так что мы увидим все, что выдает компилятор (jsc). Теперь с его помощью мы можем прогнать интересные API через JS и посмотреть, как он себя поведет.

## Эксперимент 1 - UInt32

Начнем с простого - попробуем скормить JS "некомплиантый" UInt32:

JS:

```js
class C {

    static function calc_sum(x, y) {

        return x + y;
    }
}
```

---

C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object res = JsExecute(
        "test.js",
        new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" },
        "calc_sum",
        new object[] { (uint)1, (uint)2 });
    Console.WriteLine(res);
    Console.Read();
}

/* Вывод:
3
*/
```

Как видно, все отработало без ошибок. На самом деле, это ничего толком не доказывает, так как JScript.NET, в отличие от браузерного эквивалента, поддерживает uint нативно (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ddacxdt5%28v%3dvs.100%29). Но по крайней мере наш экспериментальный код работает.

## Эксперимент 2 - Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration

Рассмотрим упомянутую Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration. К счастью, она совместима с новыми версиями .NET Framework. Для проверки напишем такой код на JS, который создает ConfigurationBuilder, устанавливает значение в словаре Properties и пытается считать его обратно:

```js
import Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

class C {

    static function test() {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.Properties['key'] = 'Value';
        return builder.Properties['key'];
    }
}
```

---

C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object res = JsExecute(
        "test.js",
        new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll", "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll" },
        "test",
        new object[] { });
    Console.WriteLine(res);

    Console.Read();
}

/* Вывод:
Value
*/
```

Опять же, все работает прекрасно. Ну, тоже нет ничего удивительно - все типы ложаться на систему типов JS.

## Эксперимент 3 - Указатели

Теперь возьмем то, что JS действительно не поддерживает - указатели. Само собой, напрямую указатель мы даже передать не можем, но есть API типа [Pointer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.pointer?view=netframework-4.5).Box/Unbox, IntPtr которые позволяют заворачивать указатели для отражения. И они, как вы можете догадаться, CLSCompliant(false). Напишем код, который передает указатель в JS, а в коде на JS попытаемся поработать с ним доступными в нем средствами:

JS:

```js
import System;
import System.Reflection;
import System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class C {

    static function write_value(p) {
        var ptr = new IntPtr(Pointer.Unbox(p));
        Marshal.WriteInt32(ptr, 1);
    }

}
```

---

C#

```
unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("x before: "+x.ToString());

    object res = JsExecute(
        "test.js",
        new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll", "System.Runtime.dll" },
        "write_value",
        new object[] { Pointer.Box(&x, typeof(int*))});

    Console.WriteLine("x  after: " + x.ToString());

    Console.Read();
}

/* Вывод:
x before: 0
x  after: 1
*/
```

Как видим, не только нет никаких предупреждений на использование 2 методов с CLSCompliant(false), но и код успешно смог установить значение переменной по указателю. Разгадка в том, что под капотом все работает на отражении, и JS нигде не встречает необходимость создать непосредственно переменную-указатель. Это не значит, что любые API на указателях можно использовать таким образом. Если API принимает не void*, а допустим byte* - уже непонятно, как его преобразовать.

---

Словом, значение CLSCompliantAttribute в современном мире .NET не так уж велико. Он нужен больше чтобы заткнуть сам компилятор C# и отдельные анализаторы FxCop, которые ругаются на его отсутствие, чем для реальной интеграции языков. Некоторые решают игнорировать предупреждение и не ставить атрибут, чтобы сэкономить на размере бинарника. Но если просто удалить атрибут, сломается код, который от него зависит, что и приводит к ситуации "не нужен даже создателям, но не удалить".